# Azure AD b2c: When trying to access b2c, maui app crahes, without it works

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, maui

i am trying to access my app with my just set up azure ad b2c.
This is working code:

```
    public AuthService()
    {
        authenticationClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Constants.ClientId)
            //.WithB2CAuthority(Constants.AuthoritySignIn) // uncomment to support B2C
#if WINDOWS
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost");
#else
            .WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ClientId}://auth")
#endif
            .Build();
    }
```

This will open up the login window in my application and allow me to sign in. Once I did, I am receiving the token with my information on it.

If I now uncomment the line .WithB2CAuthorty(), the app crashes before even trying to access anything.

These are my constants:

```
public static readonly string ClientId = "xxxx";
        public static readonly string[] Scopes = new string[] { "openid", "offline_access" };
       public static readonly string TenantName = "skillbasedauth";
       public static readonly string TenantId = $"{TenantName}.onmicrosoft.com";
       public static readonly string SignInPolicy = "B2C_1_client";
       public static readonly string AuthorityBase = $"https://{TenantName}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{TenantId}/";
       public static readonly string AuthoritySignIn = $"{AuthorityBase}{SignInPolicy}";
```

If one works, but the otherone doesnt, it must be an error with either the constants or the way the b2c is configured.

Got any ideas on that?